# Can I run a unity web player game on android?

Tags: javascript, android, unity-game-engine

I want to run web player games on android. I searched the internet for hours but I can't found anything about it. I don't care about touch control support. I want a starting point to run web player game android. What should I do? I'm waiting for your answer.

Comment: If you go to File ► Build Settings and export to Android or maybe WebGL it should work. You should be able to play HTML5 games on android?

Comment: Please show us at least a code sample of what you have done.

Comment: I just have a .unity3d file of a web player game.

Comment: If your game is hosted on web somewhere, what happens when you navigate to it using an Android device?

Answer (score 1):

Export the game to android and you should be able to run it on an android device.
But make sure to adjust the template and the screen resolution configurations

Comment: That is how you build for Android, but OP is asking for help getting a WebGL build running in a browser on an Android device if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

If you compile a game for HTML5 and put it on a server to be accessed by any computer, a smartphone is also capable of running it directly from the browser. The webPlayer put an alert that it is not possible to run it on smartphones, but when you click Ok it loads the game normally (it just takes a while depending on the size of the game).